# Use of Proximity Node and Set Material in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

In a "Geometry Nodes" I use the "Proximity" node to set a different material if the distance between a cube and each face is less than a specific value.

It works fine, but now I would like the faces that have had their material changed to not change again when the cube distance is greater than the specific value.

Any ideas?

[image]
The cube

[image]
The nodes used.

[The cube in action](https://youtu.be/hjwmCk7ZoW4)

[image]

Thanks for your time and help!

:)

Comment: The easy way would be to use dynamic paint. There is probably some other way to do it now with the simulation nodes that I haven't tried yet

Comment: I haven't thought about dynamic paint. I'll look it thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. double your plane, rename it to "save", give it this GN modifier:

[image]

[image]

2. in your plane, make a nodegroup of your node tree, then change your node tree to this:

[image]

3. result:

[image]

of course you have to change the behaviour of your cube, because i don't think you want that behaviour - but this is another question ;)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would never have thought to do it this way. Thanks Chris !

Comment: you can do it more "elegant" with the new simulation nodes - but i am not sure whether the new GN version would be ok for you...

Comment: I have the version 3.2.0. You would change to the new version 3.4.1?

Comment: it depends...as usual ;) if you are working with Blender "just for fun" and not for customers - i would recommend using the newest so you learn the new things very early ;) and you can use the newest crazy features at first! ;) i am working with 3.6.... ;)

Comment: No doubt, this night i will upgrade Blender.
Thanks ! :)